# URL to function in views.py from jquery

Tags: jquery, django, django-views

I have read the 2 posts related to this subject. Can't make them apply to my case:

After lots of wrestling, I have solved some things but I am not indicating the URL to the view function correctly FROM the jquery code. I thought that I could do it by using the name that you give when you create your paths at urls.py but it won't work.

Then, how are you supposed to write your url to a function inside the views.py file?

My jquery file is located inside /static/js and it goes like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
        var valor = $(this).val();
        $.post('../home', {valor:valor}, function(data){

       });


       });

});
```

AND THE VIEW DOES NOT CATCH IT:

```
def home(request):
    topic = request.POST.get('valor')
    print(topic)
```

Comment: Is the code you show above your real code? Because `request.POST.get(valor)` will definitely raise a `ValueError` since `valor` isn't defined. It should be `request.POST.get("valor")`.

Comment: yes, the IDE indicated that it wanted "" and I added them. I approach the issues separately now, otherwise, nobody answers. Now I need to find the way to correctly indicate the URL to the view function.

Comment: Set a variable in your template: `<script>var queryUrl =“{% url “home” %}”</script>`. Then use that (global) variable in your script.

Comment: Check the quotes. Don’t copy paste from here because my quotes are the wrong ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `JSON.stringify` in your jquery code:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
    var valor = $(this).val();
    $.post('../home', JSON.stringify({valor:valor}), function(data){

   });

   });
});
```

and in your view use this code:

```
def home(request):
    topic = request.data.get('valor')
    print(topic)
```

Comment: you must remove name='home' from url path. like this: url(r'^$', views.home). and also edit your jquery post request to '/' path.

Comment: OK but this is another problem and un related to this question. You can ask another question for your problem and explain it in more detail.

Comment: I solved the issue with the URL, now it is a forbidden 403 and as I have learned it is due to the lack of csrf token. I am looking into solving that now too.

Comment: You should use @csrf_exempt decoration to solve this problem. You can import this decorator like this: from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt. but as I said these are unrelated to question. If this answer solve your problem mark it as accepted.

Answer (score -1):

1. You are using ajax thus the django view should not return render. Check how to render the response in [render_to_string](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/templates/)
2. The html you get from render to string, return it as json as the data using return JsonReponse(). Always remember to provide status.
3. Once the data is received back in the ajax post, append it a div. This will be displayed as a normal view template and formatted with the existing css in your page.

Comment: that page doesn't mention the word ajax or jquery.
Besides, first I do display the full table when someone lands on the page, but I have added radio buttons for people to filter the table database. 
So, first the full table is displayed and only then someone may decide to filter it.

Comment: Those are the steps you need to follow to get the listoflanguages displayed in your view since you are using ajax to make the request to server.

Comment: I don't agree with this answer. It's perfectly valid to return an HTML snippet in response to an ajax query, if the purpose is then to insert that piece of HTML somewhere in the document (so 1. and 2. are incorrect).